# How to resolve error reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter while fetching from morning star

Tags: java, xpath, sax

i am trying to extract the fund rating which is shown as number of stars in the morning star website. You can see it before the word Bronze in the below link. Below is my code to get the value , but I am getting an error '[Fatal Error] :5:218: The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter.'. Not sure how to resolve this issue or why is it showing up?

URL trying to get the value from
https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000WYA1

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MSExtrctor {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000WYA1";
    HttpURLConnection connection = connect(url);
    int responseCode = 0;
    try {
        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
             XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//span[contains(@class,'rating_sprite star')]/@class");
           
            String starVal = evaluateStr(document, expr);
            System.out.println(starVal);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Response " + responseCode + " from URL : " + url);
    }

}

private static String evaluateStr(Document document, XPathExpression xPathExpression){
    String str = null;
    try {
        str = (String) xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}

private static HttpURLConnection connect(String urlStr) {
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlStr);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConnection.connect();
        return httpConnection;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return httpConnection;
}
```

}

**Error trace**

```
[Fatal Error] :5:218: The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 218; The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:261)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:122)
```

Comment: why are you doing this twice `document = builder.parse(connection.getInputStream());` && `Document documentBuider = builder.parse(connection.getInputStream());`

Comment: It's because you are trying to parse HTML with an XML parser. `'&l='+l` looks like an entity to an XML parser.

Comment: Scary Wombat - i have removed the duplicate getConnection .

Comment: @tgdavies - how can I fix it. similar code has been working fine with other websites like fidelity where i am scraping html data.

Comment: Using tagsoup is the usual suggestion. I haven't used it personally.

Comment: [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) is what I've used successfully for HTML parsing

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because you are treating the data coming from the site as XML, and it isn't well-formed XML.

If it's advertised as XML (e.g if it's delivered with an XML media type) then the site is faulty and you should complain to them, or take your custom elsewhere.

If it's advertised as HTML then you should parse it using an HTML parser not an XML parser.